# zip warning: 'name not matched' inside bash loop for

Tags: bash, zip

I'm trying to build a plugin which has the following base script inside its makefile:

```
$(ZIP_FILE):
    git archive --format zip --prefix $(NAME)/ --output $(ZIP_FILE) HEAD
    mkdir -p $(NAME)/resources/bin
    ln -s `pwd`/addon.xml $(NAME)
    zip -9 -r -g $(ZIP_FILE) $(NAME)/addon.xml
    for arch in $(ARCHS); do \
        ln -s `pwd`/resources/bin/$$arch $(NAME)/resources/bin/$$arch; \
        zip -9 -r -g $(ZIP_FILE) $(NAME)/resources/bin/$$arch; \
    done
```

Yet, I can't figure out why this error pops up every time:

```
zip warning: name not matched: plugin.video.pulsar/resources/bin/windows_x86
```

And repeats for each arch....??

P.S. this is what it looks like inside terminal:

```
git archive --format zip --prefix plugin.video.pulsar/ --output plugin.video.pulsar-0.4.6.zip HEAD
mkdir -p plugin.video.pulsar/resources/bin
ln -s `pwd`/addon.xml plugin.video.pulsar
zip -9 -r -g plugin.video.pulsar-0.4.6.zip plugin.video.pulsar/addon.xml
updating: plugin.video.pulsar/addon.xml (deflated 59%)
for arch in windows_x86 darwin_x64 linux_x86 linux_x64 linux_arm; do \
        ln -s `pwd`/resources/bin/$arch plugin.video.pulsar/resources/bin/$arch; \
        zip -9 -r -g plugin.video.pulsar-0.4.6.zip plugin.video.pulsar/resources/bin/$arch; \
done
        zip warning: name not matched: plugin.video.pulsar/resources/bin/windows_x86

zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip -9 -r -g plugin.video.pulsar-0.4.6.zip . -i plugin.video.pulsar/resources/bin/windows_x86)
        zip warning: name not matched: plugin.video.pulsar/resources/bin/darwin_x64
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [zip command not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529851/zip-command-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

It's because that file (`plugin.video.pulsar/resources/bin/windows_x86`) really [does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529851/zip-command-not-working).